# Bash script that just accepts an SSH handshake

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

I need to have a script or command that just accepts a handshake to add a key to the `known_hosts` file.

I tried with `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new user@ip`, but I have the problem that it asks for the password:

```
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.178.xx' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
user@IP's password:
```

I need something where I just jump back to the console. Any hint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ssh-keyscan`:

> `ssh-keyscan` is a utility for gathering the public SSH host keys of a number of hosts.  It was designed to aid in building and verifying
> ssh_known_hosts files.

```
ssh-keyscan -H ip >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

You might first want to remove the address to avoid duplicates:

```
ssh-keygen -R ip
```